# RelativeLayout to the right instead of on top

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

How can i make the imageViews land beside eachother and not on top of eachother?

```
    public void deckButtonOnClick(View v) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    imageView.setImageResource(DECK.takeCard());
    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(PARAMS);
    imageView.setTag("0");
    imageView.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener());

    ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.innerRelativeLayout)).addView(imageView);

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:** Rework your container for the cards as a LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout, using orientation="horizontal".

**Option 2:** Using the RelativeLayout, you'll need to give each imageView you create an ID (maybe increment a counter each time one is created and append it to the ID). Then, when you are creating your PARAMS variable, you can [add a rule](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule%28int,%20int%29) to align to the right of the previous ImageView.

```
PARAMS = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
PARAMS.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.imageView1);
imageView.setLayoutParams(PARAMS);
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems from your Option 1 that it is preferable, i will try this and get back to you

Comment: Okay, that clearly works. I had it like this before but my animations gets messed up now. I'll give this a little more thought

Comment: Sounds like you passed one hurdle - good luck with the animations!

Answer (score 0):

In xml, use android:layout_toRightOf=id.

In code, use imageView.setLayoutParams() with a RelativeLayout.LayoutParams and use params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, id);